# Timeseries differencing - ArangoDB (AQL or Python)

Tags: arangodb

I have a collection which holds documents, with each document having a data observation and the time that the data was captured.
e.g.
{
_key:....,
"data":26,
"timecaptured":1643488638.946702
}

where timecaptured for now is a utc timestamp.

What I want to do is get the duration between consecutive observations, with SQL I could do this with LAG for example, but with ArangoDB and AQL I am struggling to see how to do this at the database. So effectively the difference in timestamps between two documents in time order. I have a lot of data and I don't really want to pull it all into pandas.

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Which arangodb version do you use? 3.8 introduced the new WINDOW operation which should help in this scenario: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/operations-window.html

Comment: Hi mpoeter. I have 3.8 and I thought that window would help, but unfortunately I cannot figure out how to do a difference, only aggregations. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 2):

Although the solution provided by CodeManX works, I prefer a different one:

```
FOR d IN docs
  SORT d.timecaptured
  WINDOW { preceding: 1 } AGGREGATE s = SUM(d.timecaptured), cnt = COUNT(1)
  LET timediff = cnt == 1 ? null : d.timecaptured - (s - d.timecaptured)
  RETURN timediff
```

We simply calculate the sum of the previous and the current document, and by subtracting the current document's `timecaptured` we can therefore calculate the `timecaptured` of the previous document. So now we can easily calculate the requested difference.

I only use the `COUNT` to return `null` for the first document (which has no predecessor). If you are fine with having a difference of zero for the first document, you can simply remove it.

However, neither approach is very straight forward or obvious. I put on my TODO list to add an `APPEND` aggregate function that could be used in WINDOW and COLLECT operations.

Comment: Thank you to both of you. This has definitely been very helpful and solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

The `WINDOW` function doesn't give you direct access to the data in the sliding window but here is a rather clever workaround:

```
FOR doc IN collection
  SORT doc.timecaptured
  WINDOW { preceding: 1 }
  AGGREGATE d = UNIQUE(KEEP(doc, "_key", "timecaptured"))
  LET timediff = doc.timecaptured - d[0].timecaptured
  RETURN MERGE(doc, {timediff})
```

The `UNIQUE()` function is available for window aggregations and can be used to get at the desired data (previous document). Aggregating full documents might be inefficient, so a projection should do, but remember that `UNIQUE()` will remove duplicate values. A document `_key` is unique within a collection, so we can add it to the projection to make sure that `UNIQUE()` doesn't remove anything.

The time difference is calculated by subtracting the previous' documents `timecaptured` value from the current document's one. In the case of the first record, `d[0]` is actually equal to the current document and the difference ends up being `0`, which I think is sensible. You could also write `d[-1].timecaptured - d[0].timecaptured` to achieve the same. `d[1].timecaptured - d[0].timecaptured` on the other hand will give you the inverted timestamp for the first record because `d[1]` is `null` (no previous document) and evaluates to `0`.

There is one risk: `UNIQUE()` may alter the order of the documents. You could use a subquery to sort by `timecaptured` again:

```
LET timediff = doc.timecaptured - (
  FOR dd IN d SORT dd.timecaptured LIMIT 1 RETURN dd.timecaptured
)[0]
```

But it's not great for performance to use a subquery. Instead, you can use the aggregation variable `d` to access both documents and calculate the absolute value of the subtraction so that the order doesn't matter:

```
LET timediff = ABS(d[-1].timecaptured - d[0].timecaptured)
```